# Why using PHP Mailer inside a foreach to loop through all recipients won't work? What's wrong with my forearch loop?

Tags: php, email, foreach, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email to each recipient of a list (the recipient is taken from a database query, and the email is sent to all that are "checked", using `$_POST['enviar']` in each checkbox to reference each one.

The code does work as intended when using **mail()**, but it doesn't when I'm using **PHPMailer**, it just send the email to the first recipient.

So I assume that I'm doing the foreach wrong? How may I correct it?

```
  if ($correo=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conectar,$query))) {
      $total=array();
      $total=count($_POST['enviar']);
      $id = $_POST['enviar'];            
      foreach ($id as $item) {
              include 'private/enviarMails.php'; //PHP Mailer credentials
              $mail->addAddress($item);
              $mail->Subject = $correo['mailAsunto'];
              $mail->Body    = $correo['mailMensaje'];
              if(!$mail->send()) {
                  echo 'El mail no se mandó: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
              } else { echo 'Se envi&oacute; un correo a '.$item;}


      }
  } else { echo 'No se pudieron enviar los correos'; }
      mysqli_close($conectar);  
}
```

Comment: You do realize that you are including the same file with every iteration of that loop, right?

Comment: Yes, the file contains my SMTP sending credentials.

Comment: Right, but do you need to include that file more than once? I don't think so.

Comment: You were right, that was the problem, I was redeclaring the Mailer Autoload function, thanks! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have made this answer. Glad it resolved your issue. :)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the mailing list exampel provided with PHPMailer. It's much more efficient than what you're doing here. Your current code will send the first message to the first recipient, the second message to the first *and* second recipient and so on. You're missing a call to `clearAddresses` inside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are including your credentials in every page loop.

Change:

```
foreach ($id as $item) {
    include 'private/enviarMails.php'; //PHP Mailer credentials
    $mail->addAddress($item);
```

To:

```
include 'private/enviarMails.php'; //PHP Mailer credentials
foreach ($id as $item) {
    $mail->addAddress($item);
```